# Adding generic properties to a class insert Dynamically

Tags: c#, .net, class

I have to build up a set of generic properties which are set using incident class if the object in the array contains a $ in its name it should be access via an generic property of type incident.

```
 string[] props = { "Id", "Status", "Title","Description" ,"$Fullname$"};

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for (int i = 0; i < props.Length; i++)
        {
            if (props[i].ToLowerInvariant().Contains('$'))
            {
                if (props[i] == "$Fullname$")
                {
                    sb.Append("Fullname=emop.Object.Fullname");

                }

            }


        }
```

What I was thinking of doing was creating a string builder using the following but of course. I have no way of doing this in the class constructor as the class wont no Full name is meant to be a property of class incident until run time.

```
            Incident incident = new Incident()
            {
                InternalId = emop.Object.Id,
                Id = emop.Object[null, "Id"] != null ? emop.Object[null, "Id"].ToString() : string.Empty,
                Title = emop.Object[null, "Title"] != null && emop.Object[null, "Title"].Value != null ? emop.Object[null, "Title"].Value.ToString() : string.Empty,
                Name = emop.Object.Name,
                sb.ToString(), //OUTPUT the generic properties
                LastModified = emop.Object.LastModified,
                Description = emop.Object[null, "Description"] != null && emop.Object[null, "Description"].Value != null ? emop.Object[null, "Description"].Value.ToString() : string.Empty
            };
```

Comment: So, your question is?

Comment: What you are trying to do wouldnt be so easy really. Did you consider just making a key value dictionary with custom properties instead? This just looks like a hacky solution to a potentially trivial problem?

Comment: you can try with ExpandoObject, more info here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/62839/Adventures-with-C-dynamic-ExpandoObject-Elasti